# What is a error here in ExecJS::RuntimeError in Statuses#index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcvxb.png

I have created a project named Treebook then after I added a code "rails generate scaffold status name:string context:text" which created my class as

*class CreateStatuses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :statuses do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :context
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end*

then after opening my localhost i got an error which is shown in above link .

Comment: Is rubyracer uncommented in your gemfile?

Comment: @Santosh what do that mean?

Comment: There is a gem which is commented by default in the gemfile called `therubyracer`. Uncomment this and rebundle

Comment: can you please tell me how to uncomment that and rebundle? i am just the beginner

Answer (score 1):

I had the error too on a Win7 system and installed node.js which fixed it (I tried the fix with rubyracer but it didn't worked for me). Maybe this will fix it.

For your ubuntu system (as I presume by your image) you can install nodejs
by entering this command into a console

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```